# Problems in compiling x86 asm and inline-asm in ffmpeg to WebAssembly

Tags: assembly, ffmpeg, webassembly

Sorry I'm new to WebAssembly(wasm) and working on a project decoding videos on browser with ffmpeg and wasm to improve the performance.

I have used Emscripten(emcc) to compile ffmpeg to wasm and got things worked. However, as Emscripten cannot compile inline assembly code, video decoding with wasm on web is almost **3-5 times slower** than native decoding without asm supported, and the cpu usage could be really high.

As far as I know, wasm is a stack-based vm while asm is cpu specific, but without asm, wasm is quite **far away from** the aim to native speed. After some day searching on the basic concept of wasm and asm etc. I have known some compilers like **nasm** to perform **cross-platform asm**, are there some compiler frontend to have llvmir and asm instructions together so that to have **inline-asm and asm-supported** in wasm?

Comment: NASM is only cross-platform in that it can be run on potentially many different platforms, not that it produces machine code that can be run on any platform other than x86 CPUs.  WebAbbsembly isn't going to provide a means to generate arbitrary machine code for the target platform (eg. x86) as that would defeat it's purpose which is to be a "safe" VM environment, similar to Java VMs.

Answer (score 3):

To complement szatmary answer, there is actually no way to transform x86 code to wasm bytecode. As so, C compilers that target wasm are simply ignoring inline asm directives (be it x86, ARM, whatever).

I suppose it could be possible in theory, but I doubt someone would do it. The use cases are really thin IMHO. People are writing inline x86 to try to optimize  performance bottlenecks, but this come at the cost of portability. And portability is one of the major goals of Wasm...

The performance hit you have is not because of lack of x86 support. It is simply because wasm is bytecode, and this will never be as fast as native code. Maybe a JIT could help there, but don't have too big expectations.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no x86 to wasm compiler without using C, or another higher level language as an intermediary.

Comment: Sorry to have a misunderstanding question title, I'm compiling x86 inline asm in C actually, any idea about inline-asm? Thanks alot!

Comment: @Sparkmorry: C + x86 inline asm only works if it can compile to x86 asm, not other targets like WASM.